# How to apply the border spacing on table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I currently have problem on my table which is I need to have a margin on my `<th></th>` tag
I already test the border-spacing on w3school yes it works there however on my side the border-spacing of css is not working.

CSS Framework: SB-Admin2

Html5

Backend Framework: Laravel

W3School Output:

[image: W3 School Output]

```
    <table class="table table-bordered agent_commission_models" style="border-spacing: 10px;">

              <thead>
                <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center; ">
                 <th colspan="1"  style="border-left-color:white; border-right-color: white; border-top-color: white; border-bottom-color: white;"></th>
                  <th colspan="2" style="vertical-align:top; text-transform:uppercase; color:white; background-color: #8092AB;" class="flash_period_text_onchange">
                    2020
                  </th>

                  <th colspan="2" class="bg-gradient-success" style="vertical-align:top; color:white; background-color: #009700; position:relative;">TGT</th>

                  <th colspan="2" class="bg-gradient-dark"  style="vertical-align:top; color:white; background-color: #808080;">LY</th>

                  <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup" style="color:black;">Variance Vs Target</th>
                  <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup" style="color:black;">Variance Vs <?php echo $future=date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')); ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="header_2nd_level">
                  <th style="border-left-color:white; border-right-color: white;"></th>
                  <th style="border-left-color:white; border-right-color: white;"></th>
                  <th style="border-left-color:white; border-right-color: white;"></th>
                  <th style="border-left-color:white; border-right-color: white;"></th>
                  <th style="border-left-color:white; border-right-color: white;"></th>
                  <th style="border-left-color:white; border-right-color: white;"></th>
                  <th style="border-left-color:white;"></th>
                  <th>amount</th>
                  <th>%</th>
                  <th>ppt</th>

                  <th>amount</th>
                  <th>%</th>
                  <th>ppt</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
</table>
```

**On my side output:**

**Note: This image code is same on the w3school**

[image: My Side output]

Hope someone encounter this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `border-spacing` property doesn't work if the `border-collapse = "collapse"` for this add `border-collapse = "separate"` to your table.

**Note :** This property works only when *border-collapse* is separate.

Hope  this might help you.

Comment: Is border-collapse allow in table header?

Comment: No,it is mandatory to use it in the table only or else it won't work.

Comment: yah your answer is correct, but is it allowed to use the border-collapse in <th><th> tag?

Comment: Is there way to put spacing between those <th></th> tag?

Comment: Yes! ,you can absolutely do it but this time not by `border-spacing` property for this you just have to increase the width of the `<table></table>` and make `<th></th>` border free

Comment: do you have example for that Kunal?

Comment: Yes!,(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-collapse) here is the given example just change the above mentioned steps in the example and you will get what you want.

Comment: @SoulAiker If my answer helped you in anyway can you please accept it?